# Drools 7: use entry point from consequence (RHS)

Tags: drools

How do I insert into an entry point on RHS?

From Mastering JBoss Drools 6 book

```
rule "Routing.."
when
...
then entryPoints["Stream Y"].insert(t)
end
```

I'm trying to make this work using Drools 7 but I get an error `Unable to build KieBaseModel`.

EDIT: Full message:

```
Unable to Analyse Expression drools.entryPoints["Stream Y"].insert(t);:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper.entryPoints()]
[Near : {... drools.entryPoints["Stream Y"].insert ....}]
```

Note: I've not defined any global called `entrypoints`.

Comment: Do you have the full error message you are getting?

Comment: Hi! I've added error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `entryPoints` automagic variable is not there anymore in Drools 7.
You can try something like this though:

```
rule "Routing.."
when
    ...
then 
    drools.getEntryPoint("Stream Y").insert(t)
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Hi and thank you! In my rules I was using dialect "mvel". I found entryPoints["Stream Y"] only works with java dialect. I did not realize this could affect this so I left it out of the question.. Also I had no rules using entry point on LHS. Your answer drools.getEntrypoint works both with java and mvel.